# Cross product with elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$A = \{a, b, c\}$ and $B= \{b, \{c\}\}$

$b \in A \times B$ is false.

Why is it false? Is it false because the element $b$ is already in both sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements of $A \times B$ are *tuples*, $b$ is not a tuple.

Comment: Why can't it be that $b=\{c,\{c,\{c\}\}\}=(c,\{c\})$? After all, $b$ and $c$ can be chosen freely among the sets.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli i don't understand how you can choose $c$ so that $\{c,\{c, \{c\}\}\} = (c,\{c\})$

Comment: That's [Kuratowski's definiton of ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition) in ZFC. It does not really matter which definition we choose, the point is: $(c,\{c\})$ is a set which is defined independently of the choice of $b$.

Comment: Well, it seems I was imprecise: I should have written $\{\{c\},\{c,\{c\}\}\}$, but the point stands.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I see now. You are implying that $b$ and $c$ can be chosen cleverly so that $b \in A \times B$. But this cannot be, since the OP clearly put down the assumption that $b \not \in A \times B$ into the question... But thanks for the lesson, I appreciate it